# Colors (red, for example) are printing gray instead of red

Tags: drivers, printing

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop. Today I printed a document that has an image with a red border. The print preview showed the red border. My printer is an HP Color Laser Jet Pro M277dw. I’ve had it for 5 years, and I’ve printed many pages with color borders around images, and the red borders always printed red. Today the border did not print red. I suspect it’s a printer driver problem. I looked at the printer settings that the new operating system provides, but I saw nil about the current printer driver. Per the Synaptic package manager, CUPS and HPLIP are installed on my computer. My main question now is: How do I discover the current printer driver that’s in use now?

Comment: Not sure this will solve it, but - when you select 'Print', in the dialog box that opens, look in Properties then under the Devices tab, look to see what colour options are selected. There's a greyscale option that might have been selected?